# SQL - select both "child" and "parent" rows in a single query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a database filled with a lot of "empty" records and I want to get rid of those orphaned records.

**The database is structured like this;**

1. A *child row* that contains the real entry (meta_value)
2. A *parent row* that is "linked" to its child (by it's meta_key)

---

`|  meta_id        post_id       meta_key        meta_value   |
|                                                            |
|  011            301           ACF__P_01_01    Foo          |
|  012            309           _ACF__P_01_01   field_5874d5 |
|  013            321           ACF__P_01_02                 |
|  014            316           _ACF__P_01_02   field_54290a |
|  015            119           ACF__P_01_03    Bar          |
|  016            101           _ACF__P_01_03   field_a04a88 |
|  017            119           ACF__P_01_03                 |
|  018            101           _ACF__P_01_03   field_a04a88 |
|  019            149           ACF__P_01_03                 |
|  020            111           _ACF__P_01_03   field_a04a88 |
|  021            169           ACF__P_01_03    Foo Bar      |
|  022            171           _ACF__P_01_03   field_a04a88 |`

---

It's easy to select all the (empty) "child" rows, with a query like this;

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    wp_postmeta
WHERE
    wp_postmeta.meta_key LIKE '%ACF__%'
AND
    wp_postmeta.meta_value LIKE ''
```

But this query only fetches the (empty) "child" rows, not their "parent" row.

---

There are two logical conditions that bind the parent to the child;

1. The **first row** is always the child, **immediately followed** by its parent.
2. The parent row has the same "**meta_key**" value as it's child, but **pre-fixed by an underscore**.

---

Is there any way to create a SQL query that selects the empty child records (like I did above) **and** it's parent as well?

I prefer a single query to fetch them both - but when that's not possible, I could run two queries as well (*first one to fetch the parent, second one to get the empty children, I guess*).

I use **Navicat** for my database management, so it must be plain SQL - no PHP.

---

**The query should spit out the results like this;**

---

`|  meta_id        post_id       meta_key        meta_value   |
|                                                            |
|  013            321           ACF__P_01_02                 |
|  014            316           _ACF__P_01_02   field_54290a |
|  017            119           ACF__P_01_03                 |
|  018            101           _ACF__P_01_03   field_a04a88 |
|  019            149           ACF__P_01_03                 |
|  020            111           _ACF__P_01_03   field_a04a88 |`

---

So both the empty-childs (no value in the "meta_value") and it's parent (both have the same "meta_key", where the parent has an underscore.

Comment: looks like a parent row always has a meta_value, why not use it in your where clause?
where ( wp_postmeta.meta_key LIKE '%ACF__%' AND     wp_postmeta.meta_value LIKE '') or  (wp_postmeta.meta_key LIKE '%ACF__%' AND     wp_postmeta.meta_value <>'') ;  then sort the output as you like

Comment: how the result you want looks like (please give example from the data in the question above)?

Comment: do you know if Navicat  has common table expression or not??

Comment: I guess Navicat is just sending it's commands to my database? So it's the database that determines the limitations, not Navicat? But I also tried three other database-managers - and they all reported the same error... I can't figure out how to write a decent, single SQL query to fetch both parent and it's child.

Answer (score 3):

With a self-join

```
Select *
from wp_postmeta c
   join wp_postmeta p
      on p.meta_key = '_' + c.meta_key
```

The above will only fetch "pairs" of parent-child records. If it's possible to have parents without children (I assume it's not possible to have children without parents), and you want all the parents, including the childless ones, use an outer join

```
Select *
from wp_postmeta p
   left join wp_postmeta c
      on '_' + c.meta_key = p.meta_key
```

In relational databases, there is no such concept as "after" or "before" unless you define it yourself and add data into the tables that implements that concept (like a datetimestamp, or sequentially increasing numeric key, or whatever. Without such artifacts, records in a relational database table do ***not*** have any implicit order.

Comment: That looks promising; it shows all records from my table with an underscore.

But I have to filter them like I did in my initial post (field must contain "ACF__" and be empty as well).

Can I query with those filters and join them to the parent?

```SELECT
 *
FROM
 wp_postmeta
WHERE
 wp_postmeta.meta_key LIKE '%ACF__%'
AND wp_postmeta.meta_value LIKE '' c
JOIN wp_postmeta p ON p.meta_key = '_' + c.meta_key```

This results in an error;

```You have an error in your SQL syntax near 'c
JOIN wp_postmeta p ON p.meta_key = '_' + c.meta_key' at line 7```

Comment: Then you should google `join` and read up on it. Your modified query is syntactically incorrect use of `join`,  `Join` is a basic tool of database queries, and until you learn to use it you are wasting time better spent learning it. . And look again at the output, it should show all *pairs* of rows (with each *pair* in a single displayed output row) of parent, child records from the table.

Comment: I tried both examples, but it returns about 25000 rows - because they are not filtered at all (when I replace "_" by something like "foo" I got the same 25000 results)... it looks like it's doing nothing.

Comment: Please do some studying on SQL Queries... If you use `Left join` you will get the same number of rows because the join conditions only affect the fields fetched from one side of the join, you still get all the data from the other side.  Another issue is that you should not be using `Like` unless you want to use partial comparisons rather than exact comparisons. Use `=` for exact comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP I was able to solve it. I iterate over the first result from a query (that fetches all the empty children) and fetch every row AFTER that child, inside the loop.

But that's PHP - I wanted pure SQL :)

```
<?php

$connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

  if ($connection -> connect_errno > 0) {

    die ("Unable to connect to database [" . $connection->connect_error . "]");

  }

$query_1 = "SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` LIKE '%ACF%__' AND `meta_value` LIKE ''";

  if (!$result_1 = $connection -> query($query_1)) {

    die ("There was an error running query[" . $connection -> error . "]");

  }

  if ($result_1) {

    $i = 0;

    echo "<h2>ACF - empty fields</h2>";
    echo "<table border=1 cellpadding=4 cellspacing=0 width=800>";
    echo "<tr style='background:#eee;font-weight:bold;'><td>row</td><td>meta_id</td><td>post_id</td><td>meta_key</td><td>meta_value</td></tr>";

      while ($row_1 = $result_1 -> fetch_assoc()) {

        $i++;
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td width=100>" . sprintf('%03d', $i) . "</td>";
        echo "<td width=100 style='background:#aaa;color:#fff;font-weight:bold;'>" . $row_1["meta_id"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td width=100>" . $row_1["post_id"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td width=100>" . $row_1["meta_key"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td width=500>" . $row_1["meta_value"] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";

        $query_2 = "SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `meta_id` = " . ($row_1["meta_id"] + 1);

          if (!$result_2 = $connection -> query($query_2)) {

            die ("There was an error running query[" . $connection -> error . "]");

          }

          while ($row_2 = $result_2 -> fetch_assoc()) {

            $i++;
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td width=100>" . sprintf('%03d', $i) . "</td>";
            echo "<td width=100 style='background:#aaa;color:#fff;font-weight:bold;'>" . $row_2["meta_id"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td width=100>" . $row_2["post_id"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td width=100>" . $row_2["meta_key"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td width=500>" . $row_2["meta_value"] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";

          }

        mysqli_free_result($result_2);

      }

    mysqli_free_result($result_1);

    echo "</table>";

  } else {

    echo "No entries found.";

  }

?>
```

**- edit -**

This PHP code is better, I guess... It uses only 2 queries and iterates over the first one...

It works perfectly, but still isn't pure SQL - I want to get rid of the PHP...

```
<?php

/* --------------------------------------------------- */

$connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

  if ($connection -> connect_errno > 0) {

    die ("Unable to connect to database [" . $connection->connect_error . "]");

  }

/* --------------------------------------------------- */

$query = "SELECT `meta_id` FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` LIKE '%ACF%__' AND `meta_value` LIKE ''";

  if (!$result = $connection -> query($query)) {

    die ("There was an error running query[" . $connection -> error . "]");

  }

  if ($result) {

    $array = array();

      while ($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()) {

        $array[] = $row["meta_id"];
        $array[] = $row["meta_id"] + 1;

      }

    mysqli_free_result($result);

/* --------------------------------------------------- */

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `meta_id` IN (" . implode(",", array_map("intval", $array)) . ")";

      if (!$result = $connection -> query($query)) {

        die ("There was an error running query[" . $connection -> error . "]");

      }

      if ($result) {

        $i = 0;

        echo "<h2>ACF - empty fields</h2>";
        echo "<table>";
        echo "<tr><td>record</td><td>meta_id</td><td>post_id</td><td>meta_key</td><td>meta_value</td></tr>";

          while ($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()) {

            $i++;
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . sprintf('%03d', $i) . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["meta_id"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["post_id"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["meta_key"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["meta_value"] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";

          }

        mysqli_free_result($result);

        echo "</table>";

          if (isset($_GET["delete"])) {

            echo "<span>all records deleted</span>";

          } else {

            echo "<a href='?delete'>delete empty records</a>";

          }

      }

/* --------------------------------------------------- */

  } else {

    echo "No entries found.";

  }

?>
```